# Detect and generate a cloudwatch Alarm when a Task in ECS is killed or restarted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set an Alarm using Cloudwatch to detect when a Task is killed in an ECS Cluster.

I followed this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html#cw_running_task_count to set up a metric to track the number of tasks running by a service.

This is my alarm :

```
**Namespace** : AWS/ECS
**MetricName** : CPUUtilization
**ServiceName** : my_service
**ClusterName** : my_cluster
**Statistic** : Sample count
**Period** : 1minute
**Conditions** :
**Threshold type** : Static
**Whenever CPUUtilization is**... : Lower Than 1
```

But it's not working and doesn't generate an Alarm as expected. I think that this is because if the task is killed, it's recreated again automatically and quickly under 1 minute (the period set in the Alarm).

I tried to change the Period to less than a minute but AWS says ***Only a period greater than 60s is supported for metrics in the "AWS/" namespaces***

So is there a way to detect if a task is killed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set up an Event in cloudwatch to monitor on  "ECS Task State Change" and put condition on lastStatus. Here is the code for that-

```
{
      "source": [
        "aws.ecs"
      ],
      "detail-type": [
        "ECS Task State Change"
      ],
      "detail": {
        "clusterArn": [
          "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:1234567891234:cluster/mycluster",
        ],
        "containers": {
          "lastStatus": [
            "STOPPED"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: That is true, and I just managed to create an alarm, that is triggering, when this rule sends an SQS message. However I'm not sure how to distinguish between service stoppages and just deployments, that also cause the previous version to stop.

Comment: Here's a tutorial btw: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet2.html

Answer (score 0):

- According to [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ecs-event-types) you can trigger an event from ECS.
- [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html#ecs_task_events) eventually you can track a stop event from a task. That way you can use that event as input for a CloudWatch rule.